# how to make admin users using devise and cancan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, cancan

I set up devise and cancan, but how do I make 1 user admin and other user not admin now? 
Do I use omniauth (I want to only log in with google), devise, or cancan?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get this particular functionality within CanCan to work, you'll want to store an attribute on your Devise `User` model that indicates whether a particular user is an admin, or not.

Start by creating an attribute on your `User` table called `admin`:

```
# from command line
rails generate migration AddAdminToUser user
```

In the migration, set the default value for the `admin` attribute to `false` (or `true`, depending on what behavior you want enacted by default):

```
class AddAdminToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => true

  end
end
```

Run the migration

```
# from command line
rake db:migrate
```

In your `User` model, create a convenience method to access the value of `admin`:

```
# app/models/user.rb    
def admin?
    admin
end
```

Then, in `ability.rb`, define the abilities you want to set for each user:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin? # Admin user
      can :manage, :all
    else # Non-admin user
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

Remember – by default, a new `User` is *not* an admin. You can always enable admin privileges on an existing user in the following manner:

```
# from the Rails console
user = User.find(some_number)
user.update_attribute(:admin, true)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much! Just a question. why do you say add_column :user if user already exist because of user.rb? why not add_column :admin ?

Comment: Read the whole line: you're adding `admin` __to__ the `user` table.

Comment: I see user is table admin is column.

Comment: I think the migration should read:

`rails generate migration AddAdminToUser admin:boolean`

Answer (score 2):

```
add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => true
```

change default true to false

```
add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => false
```

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of "Up to you", but the easy was just boolean attribute to the user something like admin = true/false and then you can define ability.rb something like:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    #
    #   user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    #   if user.admin?
    #     can :manage, :all
    #   else
    #     can :read, :all
    #   end
  end
end
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. Yes I have this in my ability.rb but how do i make a user admin? this part of code only say what to do with admin user. sorry my english is not very well does this make sense?

Comment: U will create a migration with up/down methods where u will use add_column method to create such attribute to users table. Do not forget to use default value for that column.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more from devise and cancan gem & role

http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/09/29/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-part-2-restful-resources-for-administrators/